# IRB: quitting or escaping from a string/block/backtick sequence

Tags: ruby, irb

A simple example:

```
1.9.3p448 :003 > `ls #{File.expand_path('../../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
1.9.3p448 :004 > `
1.9.3p448 :005`>
1.9.3p448 :006`> }
1.9.3p448 :007`> `
1.9.3p448 :008 > `
1.9.3p448 :009`> `
1.9.3p448 :010 > )
```

Ctrl-c doesn't work here.  If I know what the expected closing character is,
then I can type that to close the sequence.  That requires mental work and
sometimes I'll get it wrong, as I did here.

Is there a way to simply tell irb that I want it to drop the input string that
it's seen so far?

Also applies to "rails console" and debugger.

**EDIT**
The answer that works for me is ctrl-c after commenting my entire irbrc file.  Ctrl-D still doesn't work for me, but YMMV

Comment: The line you have given i tried,its ok for me..

Comment: @Babai This question has nothing to do with that...

Comment: @meagar ok probably I miss understood..

Comment: ctrl-C does nothing for me and ctrl-D behaves similarly--as if I hit enter

Comment: @EricHu How you started your `IRB` ? I mean there is several option to fire it.. Did you do only `IRB` ti run it first time?

Comment: @Babai yes.  I have a `.irbrc` file.  If I comment everything in that, then `^C ^D` will kill irb, but this still doesn't answer my question.  I want to be able to kill input and *keep my irb context*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `ctrl+D` and then return; you'll get a syntax error for whatever statement you've failed to terminate, and you'll be able to start a fresh statement:

```
irb(main):001:0> ziuhas'
irb(main):002:0' ^D
irb(main):002:0>
SyntaxError: (irb):1: unterminated string meets end of file
    from /Users/matthew.eagar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: IRB itself is showing whenever any mistake like here - `kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ irb
2.0.0p0 :001 > "hi
2.0.0p0 :002"> "
 => "hi\n" 
2.0.0p0 :003 > 
`

Comment: Why then need `ctrl+D` ?

Comment: The question specifically says "If I know what the expected closing character is, then I can type that to close the sequence. That requires mental work and sometimes I'll get it wrong, as I did here." He's looking for a solution that works regardless of which unbalanced symbol has been left open.

Comment: You are not getting me.. I am telling whenever any mistake happened..then it is coming to the next `IRB` prompt.. So I can see it from there,and use why then I need `ctrl+D` ?

Comment: @Babai The point is that there may be one or more open symbols, and you may not care to figure out which one is open. The question is asking for a way to quit a statement without typing the actual character, and I'm telling him how to do it. If you don't like the question, comment on the question.

Comment: Yes I know,but if you missed that in the next prompt of IRB it will comes up like `2.0.0p0 :002">`.. So from here we can see what I missed in the previous line..

Comment: @babai The question asks what the question asks, and I've answered it. If you don't agree with premise the question, vote to close it, or go elsewhere, but please stop bothering me.

Comment: @Babai What if I typed `({({({({({({({(Hello`?? The point of the question is that he wants to know how to get out of *any given open statement* the easiest way. He doesn't want to *finish* the statement, he wants to **"drop the input string that it's seen so far"** with as little brain-power as possible. If I'm rude, it's because you're *not reading the question*, but instead harassing *me* for clarification instead of the question's author.

Comment: @meager  I think you understand my intent the closest.  I want to kill an input sequence without losing my irb (or rails console or debugger) context.  `^D <enter>` doesn't give me a syntax error though.  Do you have some gem that gives you this feature?

Comment: @EricHu No; I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and both IRB and `rails console` behave identically: Regardless of what I've entered, I can return to an empty IRB prompt by pressing `CTRL-D`, followed by `<return`>.

Comment: @meagar that's strange...if I fully disable my irbrc, I still can't get `^D` to work for me--it does give me a newline, but entering in an expression that evaluates immediately, like `puts 2`, has no effect.  Either way, `^C` works for me, and it's now apparent that one of my irbrc gems was creating the issue, so thanks to you and @tadman for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Usually `^D` does this.

The alternative is the more abrupt `^C`.